# open vlc on android from shell with arguments

Tags: android, vlc-android

I followed this [guide](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/) and successfully compiled vlc for android.

I added my own codec "my_codec" and installed vlc with

```
./gradlew installVanillaX86Debug
```

Now I want to force vlc to use my code. on pc the command is

```
./vlc --codec my_codec,none sample.mp4
```

for android I tried both

```
adb shell am start -n org.videolan.vlc.debug/org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity -d file:///sdcard/sample.mp4 --es --codec my_codec,none 

adb shell am start -n org.videolan.vlc.debug/org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity -d file:///sdcard/sample.mp4 --es codec my_codec,none
```

but my codec wasn't used.

Comment: I got it working with the "-d file:///sdcard/sample.mp4" Parameter. Thanks very much for that! I'd like to play with shuffle. Do you know the switch for that? Wherefrom did you get the info about "-d"? Are there any other paramters

Answer (score 0):

more a hack than a real solution, but I eventually solved it by adding the code:

```
if(strcmp(capability,"video decoder") == 0){
  name = "my_codec,none";
}
```

to the function ***vlc_module_load*** in the file ***vlc/src/modules/modules.c***

Comment: *crying* That's no way to live.